# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise OR Visual Studio 2019 Community?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm getting the Enterprise version by the school, but I'm not sure if I should stick with it or upgrade to 2019 but only the community version. I'm currently using visual studio for simple coding in school and own projects. Any input would be helpful!

Comment: Ask your school whether you'll use any of the Enterprise features.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So please [edit] your post, list your requirements and ask for software meeting those, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specific about what features you need, but is sounds like you are a beginner so the Community edition would provide the basics you need to learn. Your classes might require a feature(s) specific to the Enterprise version, but if you still have access to that through your school then you are ok there. Only you can determine what features you need. To help you decide, [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/) is a comparison of the different versions of Visual Studio 2019 from Microsoft.